# Navigate back button with ssrs in Silverlight app

Tags: silverlight, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have a Silverlight application which has a RadHtmlPlaceholder which points to ssrs to display reports like so:

```
<telerik:RadHtmlPlaceholder SourceUrl="http://serverName/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Northwind/Employees&amp;rs:Command=render" />
```

This works fine but when I have a report that allows you to drill down to display a child report, there is no way of getting back to the parent report without having to load the whole lot again.  There doesn't seem to be an option to turn on the navigate back button toolbar option and I've seen other ways of implementing a back button by using javascript to set the window location back one in the history, but obviously this won't work in a Silverlight application.  Is there anyway to implement a navigate back button?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread over in the Telerik forums: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/htmlplaceholder/html-place-holder-back-forward-refresh.aspx

Basically you need to get a handle on the IFrame from the presenter and inject some JavaScript. The history object also has a length property you can use to evaluate if your buttons should be enabled.

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Get the IFrame from the HtmlPresenter 
            HtmlElement iframe = (HtmlElement)htmlPlaceholder.HtmlPresenter.Children[0];
            // Set an ID to the IFrame so that can be used later when calling the javascript 
            iframe.SetAttribute("id", "myIFrame");
        }

        private void Refresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Code to be executed 
            string code = "document.getElementById('myIFrame').contentWindow.location.reload(true);";
            HtmlPage.Window.Eval(code); 
        }

        private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Code to be executed 
            string code = "document.getElementById('myIFrame').contentWindow.history.back();";
            HtmlPage.Window.Eval(code); 
        }

        private void Forward_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Code to be executed 
            string code = "document.getElementById('myIFrame').contentWindow.history.forward();";
            HtmlPage.Window.Eval(code); 
        }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, more important issues have since come up so when I get round to implementing this I'll mark as answered if works ok, cheers!